# JavaScript function to return last item in row given col/row keys

Tags: javascript

I have the following object:

```
var c = { row: 1, col: 1 }
```

I need to determine if `c` is the last item in the row given the `col` \ `row` identifiers with the 'master' list resembling something like:

```
[{ row: 1, col: 2 }, { row: 2, col: 1 }, { row: 1, col: 1 }, { row: 2, col: 3 } ]
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?  Perhaps sorting but i'm not sure...

Note: the items could be in any order.

Comment: What should the output be... I think I'm misunderstanding what you are looking for. In your example, do you just want to see if `var c == { row:2, col:3 }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var c = { row: 1, col: 2 };  
var arr = [{ row: 1, col: 2 }, { row: 2, col: 1 }, { row: 1, col: 1 }, { row: 2, col: 3 } ];

var isLast = !arr.filter(function(o){ return o.row===c.row && o.col >= c.col }).length;

var c = { row: 1, col: 2 };
// false

var c = { row: 1, col: 3 };
// true
```

Comment: I like this solution, its a little cleaner than mine :)

Comment: Thanks.  I actually found yours cleaner than mine!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with:

```
 var hC = card.col;

 items.forEach(function (c) {
   if (card.row === c.row && c.col > hC) {
     hC = c.col;
   }
 }); 

 return card.col === hC;
```

Answer (score -1):

look if the propertys match

```
var c = { row: 1, col: 1 };

var masterList = [{ row: 1, col: 2 }, { row: 2, col: 1 }, { row: 1, col: 1 }, { row: 2, col: 3 }];

if( (c.row == masterList[masterList.length -1].row) && (c.col == masterList[masterList.length -1].col)){
      console.log('c equals the last entry of masterList')
}else{
      console.log('c doesnt equal the last entry of masterList');
}
```

Comment: No, it wouldn't work.  The items could be in any order.

Comment: you mean the propertys "row" and "col" ? 
i dont get you

Comment: Also, you'd have to stringify the objects to compare them with ==... `{} !== {}` in javascript.

Comment: yes i wasnt too sure, updated the answer comparing the objects propertys

Comment: You could probably even just do `console.log(JSON.stringify(c) == JSON.stringify(master[master.length - 1]));`

Comment: ah length isnt nullbased, yep that stringify attempt would work